# Can Knex do "HAVING COUNT(col) > x" without resorting to raw?

Tags: typescript, knex.js

I want to build the following query using knex (in typescript), and I'm puzzled by the HAVING COUNT. The knex website seems to indicate that it can only be done with [HavingRaw](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-havingRaw), but I'm curious if there is solution without using raw SQL.

The query in SQL:

```sql
SELECT UserId, COUNT(UserId)
FROM [MyTable] 
WHERE UserId IS NOT NULL 
AND OrderDate BETWEEN '2022-01-10T00:00:00.000Z' AND '2022-01-14T23:59:59.999Z'
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING COUNT(UserId) >= 5
```

My current implementation:

```typescript
    const mainQuery = knexDb('MyTable')
        .select('UserId')
        .count('UserId')
        .whereNotNull('UserId')
        .whereBetween('TargetDate', [date1, date2])
        .groupBy('UserId')
        .havingRaw('COUNT(UserId) >= ?', [5]);
```

I'm curious if there is a built-in, typed, alternative for the `.havingRaw('COUNT(UserId) >= ?', [5]);` part

Answer (score 2):

In your specific example you could alias the count in your select and then just reference that in the having clause. i.e.

```js
const mainQuery = knexDb('MyTable')
        .select('UserId')
        .count('UserId as UserCount')
        .whereNotNull('UserId')
        .whereBetween('TargetDate', [date1, date2])
        .groupBy('UserId')
        .having('UserCount', '>=', 5);
```

If you do not already have the column you are counting in your select then I don't think it's possible without raw currently.

Comment: In retrospect, this does not actually work, the HAVING clause apparently only accepts real column names, not calculated aliases, even when I try the underlying SQL in SSMS.

Comment: As yes sorry upon review using aliases in the HAVING clause appears to be an addition that works in mysql and postgres but not in standard SQL. Unfortunately without that there is no way to avoid `raw` until/if knex decide to add a `havingCount` function.

Comment: Thanks @Wodlo for your review!